# Python program run by systemd service unable to detect serial ports

Tags: python-3.x, cron, serial-port, systemd, beagleboneblack

I am using a systemd service to run a python script on boot which reads data from the serial ports of my device. When I run the python script in the terminal, it works fine. However, when use the systemd script, it fails to detect the serial ports.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Shell Script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/script.sh
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 90

while true
do
        which python3
        echo $(date) 
        python3 /home/debian/log_auto.py
        sleep 30
done
```

log_auto.py is the python script.

Note: the time on this device is not configured properly. Not sure if that has anything to do with this. The device I am using is a Beagle Bone Black.

I tried having the bash script that my service uses wait 90 seconds before attempting to read the serial port data, but it still did not work. I also tried using crontab and ran into the same issue.

Comment: What do you mean by stating that the script "can't detect serial ports"? Can you include that part of the script in your question? Also there shouldn't be a reason to wrap it in a bash script.